# SOAP response (XML) to JSON

Tags: javascript, xml, json, soap, titanium

I need to consume a SOAP web service which, naturally, sends its response in XML, since I'm developing a Appcelerator Titanium mobile app I would prefer the response in JSON. After looking online I converted the response using [this](http://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json) Javascript code, it mostly worked but returned results such as the following:

```
{
    "SOAP-ENV:Body" :     {
        "ns1:linkAppResponse" :         {
            "ns1:result" :             {
                #text : true;
            };
            "ns1:uuid" :             {
                #text : "a3dd915e-b4e4-43e0-a0e7-3c270e5e7aae";
            };
        };
    };
}
```

Of course the colons and hashes in the caused problems so I adjusted the code to do a substring on the name and drop off anything before the ':', then a stringified the resulting JSON, removed all the hashes and parsed the JSON again. This is a bit messy for my liking but I end up with something usable.

Here is the xmlToJson code I'm using:

```
// Changes XML to JSON
function xmlToJson(xml) {

    // Create the return object
    var obj = {};

    if (xml.nodeType == 1) {// element
        // do attributes
        if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
            obj["@attributes"] = {};
            for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
            }
        }
    } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) {// text
        obj = xml.nodeValue;
    }

    // do children
    if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
        for (var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
            var nodeName = item.nodeName.substring(item.nodeName.indexOf(":") + 1);
            if ( typeof (obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
            } else {
                if ( typeof (obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                    var old = obj[nodeName];
                    obj[nodeName] = [];
                    obj[nodeName].push(old);
                }
                obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
};

module.exports = xmlToJson;
```

Which results in the following JSON:

```
{
    Body :     {
        linkAppResponse :         {
            result :             {
                text : true;
            };
            uuid :             {
                text : "9022d249-ea8a-47a3-883c-0f4cfc9d6494";
            };
        };
    };
}
```

While this returns a JSON object I can use, I would prefer to have the resulting JSON in the following form:

```
{
    result : true;
    uuid : "9022d249-ea8a-47a3-883c-0f4cfc9d6494";
};
```

Mostly so it's less verbose and I can simply call json.result in order check if the query was successful instead of json.Body.linkAppResponse.result.text

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: JSON doesn't use `key=value`, it uses `key:value`. Are those just examples? Sorry, I didn't read your whole post

Comment: They're what's logged to the console when I call console.debug() on the JSON object returned. I noticed that it wasn't quite right but I think that's a result of the tostring function used, I will adjust my question, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Came up with a working solution, not any less dirty but it works and returns data in the format I want.

```
function soapResponseToJson(xml) {
    var json = xmlToJson(xml).Body;

    console.debug(json);

    var response = {};
    for (var outterKey in json) {
        if (json.hasOwnProperty(outterKey)) {
            temp = json[outterKey];
            for (var innerKey in temp) {
                if (temp.hasOwnProperty(innerKey)) {
                    response[innerKey] = temp[innerKey].text;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    console.debug(response);
    return response;
}

// Changes XML to JSON
function xmlToJson(xml) {

    // Create the return object
    var obj = {};

    if (xml.nodeType == 1) {// element
        // do attributes
        if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
            obj["@attributes"] = {};
            for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
            }
        }
    } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) {// text
        obj = xml.nodeValue;
    }

    // do children
    if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
        for (var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
            var nodeName = item.nodeName.substring(item.nodeName.indexOf(":") + 1).replace('#', '');
            if ( typeof (obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
            } else {
                if ( typeof (obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                    var old = obj[nodeName];
                    obj[nodeName] = [];
                    obj[nodeName].push(old);
                }
                obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
};

module.exports = soapResponseToJson;
```

**console.debug(json):**

```
{
    linkAppResponse :     {
        result :         {
            text : true;
        };
        uuid :         {
            text : "e4f78c5f-1bc2-4b50-a749-19d733b9be3f";
        };
    };
}
```

**console.debug(response):**

```
{
    result : true;
    uuid : "e4f78c5f-1bc2-4b50-a749-19d733b9be3f";
}
```

I'm going to leave this question open for a while in case someone comes up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this is a fairly ugly solution (hope it doesn't offend you :) ).
Why don't you marshal the xml to an object and then use gson or jackson to map to json.
I don't know what framework you use, in spring for example, you can use jaxb2 to marshal and jackson or gson to transform your object to json.